# Compute inverse Laplace transform with Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, integral-transforms

Since inverse Laplace transform is just an integral, while we already have `InverseLaplaceTransform` built in, can we compute it with `Integrate`? The direct implementation of [the definition of the inverse Laplace transform](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+transform+definition) seems not to work:

*In the following piece of code, `il` is the direct implementation of the Bromwich integral, elements of `ex` are all taken from the document of `InverseLaplaceTransform`.*

```
il[f_, s_, t_] := Module[{r}, 1/(2 π I) Integrate[f Exp[s t], {s, r - I ∞, r + I ∞}]]

ex = {1/(1 + s), Log[s]^2/s, Erf[5 Sqrt[s]], s/(s^2 + 1), 1/(s^2 - 4), 
      1/(1 + s + 5 s^2), 1/(1 + Sqrt[s]), E^(-s)/s, Log[s]/s^4,
      ArcTan[2/s], Gamma[s, 0, 1], PolyGamma[2, s], 
      Exp[s + 1] ExpIntegralEi[-s], 1/(s^2 + s + 1) 1/s, 1/(s^2 + 1), 
      MeijerG[{{1/3}, {}}, {{0, 1/3, 1/3, 2/3}, {}}, s^3/27]/(2 Sqrt[3] π)};

Grid[ParallelMap[{InverseLaplaceTransform[#, s, t], il[#, s, t]}&, ex], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

As shown above, `il` fails in all cases, but is there really nothing more that `Integrate` can do?

Comment: I guess it has to do with the Bromwich integral.

Comment: As it stands, *Mathematica* does not know how to do contour integrations of this sort. You can, however, supply an appropriate Hankel contour for computations like these.

Comment: Long time no see, @J.M. :) How about giving an answer? I'm not that familiar with Hankel contour.

Comment: Not having *Mathematica* on hand, I won't be able to write an answer for a while. However, the last time I looked at this, I managed to use Hankel contours for *numerically* evaluating inverse Laplace transforms; whether they'll also work symbolically, I am not as certain.

Comment: To recap: you require a *symbolic* solution resulting from `Integrate[]`, correct?

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, exactly.

Answer (score 7):

**Direct Integration**

Possible issues in performing the integrations include choice of `Assumptions`, branch cuts in the integrands, and how limits are taken.  Addressing the first of these gives five solutions.

```
il[f_, s_, t_] := Module[{r}, 1/(2 π I) Integrate[f Exp[s t], {s, r - I ∞, r + I ∞}, 
    Assumptions -> r > 2 && t > 0]]

Grid[ParallelMap[{InverseLaplaceTransform[#, s, t], il[#, s, t]} &, 
    Extract[ex, {{1}, {2}, {5}, {6}, {10}}], Method -> "FinestGrained"], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The last result does not agree with the corresponding result from `InverseLaplaceTransform`, perhaps due to the location of the branch cuts of `ArcTan[2/s]`.

**Indefinite Integrals**

Although `Integrate` returns unevaluated for all definite integrals, `il`, except those in the preceding table, `Integrate` returns indefinite integrals for many of the expressions in `ex`.  For instance,

```
int = Grid[ParallelMap[{InverseLaplaceTransform[#, s, t], 
    Integrate[# Exp[s t]/(2 π I), s, Assumptions -> t > 0]} &, 
    Extract[ex, {{1}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {14}, {15}}], Frame -> True];
```

returns results in which `s` appears only in terms of the form, `ExpIntegralEi[s t + c[t]]`, where `c[t]` is a polynomial in `t`.  For instance, `ex[[4]]` integrates to

```
(* -((I E^(I t) ExpIntegralEi[(-I + s) t])/(4 π)) 
   - (I E^(-I t) ExpIntegralEi[(I + s) t])/(4 π) *)
```

For `st` a large positive or negative imaginary number, `c[t]` can be ignored, and

```
ExpIntegralEi[s t] - ExpIntegralEi[- s t] == 2 Pi I
```

in this limit, as can be seen from Eq (7) the [Wolfram MathWorld description of this function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html) or simply by plotting the left side of this last expression.

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[ExpIntegralEi[I/x] - ExpIntegralEi[-I/x]]], {x, 0, 0.2}]
```

[image]

Hence, `int` can be simplified in this limit to

```
(int /. ExpIntegralEi[_] -> 2 Pi I) // Expand // ExpToTrig // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Inverse Laplace Transforms obtained by integration have, of course, been obtained in the first table for elements `{1, 5, 6}` of `ex`, and those transforms agree with those in the second table.  Incidentally, it may not be obvious that the two results for `ex[[15]]` in the second table are equal,  They are.

```
FullSimplify[1 - (E^(-t/2) (Sqrt[3] Cos[(Sqrt[3] t)/2] + Sin[(Sqrt[3] t)/2]))/Sqrt[3]]
    - (E^(-(-1)^(1/3) t) (-1 - I Sqrt[3] + 2 (1 + (-1)^(1/3)) E^((-1)^(1/3) t) 
        - 2 E^(I Sqrt[3] t)))/(2 (1 + (-1)^(1/3)))
(* 0 *)
```

Thus, we now have results for `{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 14, 15}` of `ex`, although the result for `ex[[10]]` does not agree with the `InverseLaplaceTransform` result, as explained above.

At first glance, the indefinite integral of `ex[[13]]` should be evaluated in a similar fashion.

```
(* -((I E^(1 + s (1 + t)) ExpIntegralEi[-s])/(2 π (1 + t))) 
   + (I E ExpIntegralEi[s t])/(2 π (1 + t)) *)
```

The second term in this expression reduces in the limit of `s t` a large imaginary number to `-(E/(1 + t))`, the result returned `InverseLaplaceTransform`.  However, the first term does not vanish in this limit but instead oscillates at an every faster rate.  Probably, this is so, because `ex[[13]]` has a branch cut along the entire positive real axis, so the path integral in the question cannot be carried out legitimately.

Indefinite integrals also can be computed for `ex[[3]]` in terms of `Erf` and `Erfi` functions, and for `ex[[9]]` (and also `ex[[2]]`) in terms of `HypergeometricPFQ` functions.  I have not attempted to obtain limits of these expressions for `s t` a large imaginary number.  `Integrate` again returns unevaluated for elements `{7, 11, 12, 16}` of `ex`.

Comment: Though not a complete answer, thanks for your effort :)

Comment: @xzczd  Thank you.  I believe that the integration contour would need to be changed to obtain most of the other answers.  In a few cases, the branch cuts might also need to be moved.

Answer (score 1):

Still, this isn't a complete answer, but a stepfoward.

There're at least 3 issues:

1. The capability of `Integrate` seems to be limited, in other words, `InverseLaplaceTransform` seems to be targetedly optimized.
2. As noticed [by bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112278/1871), the assumption `t > 0` is important to make `Integrate` work.
3. **The `r` in my `il` function actually doesn't have any effect.**

3rd item is worth elaborating. We know (OK, perhaps many of us don't know) `Integrate` doesn't have `Hold*` attribute:

```
Attributes@Integrate
(* {Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

This means the arguments of `Integrate` will be evaluated before *going into* `Integrate`. Then guess what will happen on the `r - I ∞` and `r + I ∞`?:

```
{s, r - I ∞, r + I ∞}
```

[image]

Aha, the `r` simply disappears! This feature isn't surprising, but easy to overlook.

To make the `r` play a role in integration, we modify `il` to the following:

```
ilfixed[f_, s_, t_, r_ : 10] := 
 1/(2 π I) Integrate[
   f Exp[s t] /. s -> s + r, {s, -I ∞, +I ∞}, 
   Assumptions -> t > 0]
```

Since *v13.3* `ContourIntegrate` is introduced, we'll test one more approach:

```
ilnew[f_, s_, t_, r_ : 10] := 
 1/(2 π I) ContourIntegrate[f Exp[s t], 
   s ∈ InfiniteLine[{r, 0}, {0, 1}], Assumptions -> t > 0]
```

Given that $\gamma$ (`r` in code) is an arbitrary positive constant chosen so that the contour of integration lies to the right of all singularities for inverse Laplace transform, let's first check the singularities of `ex`. Luckily `FunctionSingularities` has been introduced in *v12.2*:

```
Grid[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], N@Reduce[FunctionSingularities[#, s], s]} &, ex], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

11th result looks a bit suspicious, let's check the `ComplexPlot` for safety:

```
pic = 
   ParallelTable[
    ComplexPlot[e, {s, -10 - 10 I, 10 + 10 I}, PlotLabel -> e], {e, 
     ex}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {545.658, Null} on 2-core laptop. *)

Grid[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, pic]\[Transpose] // Map[Partition[#, 8] &] // 
   Transpose // Flatten[#, 1] &, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

OK, `FindSingularities` indeed mis-calculates `ex[[11]]`. From the analysis above, we know that, except for the special `ex[[16]]`, a naive positive $\gamma$ (`r` in code) should work in principle. Let's try it:

```
freeze = # -> Inactive@# & /@ {InverseLaplaceTransform, Integrate, 
    ContourIntegrate};

lst = 
   ParallelTable[{InverseLaplaceTransform[e, s, t], ilfixed[e, s, t, 0], 
      ilfixed[e, s, t], ilnew[e, s, t]} /. freeze, {e, ex}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1245.389, Null} on 2-core laptop. *)
```

For comparison I've also calculated the integration on $\gamma=0$. The results are as follows:

```
typeset = Function[expr, 
   If[! FreeQ[expr, Inactive], "×", expr] /. _Piecewise :> 
     "Piecewise[…]", Listable];

Grid[Prepend[
  MapIndexed[Prepend[#, #2[[1]]] &, typeset@lst] // FullSimplify[#, t > 0] &, {"", 
   "InverseLaplaceTransform", "γ = 0, Integrate", "γ = 10, Integrate", 
   "γ = 10, ContourIntegrate"}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

As we can see, by moving the contour, `Integrate` finds the correct answer for `ex[[10]]`, and finds solutions for `ex[[{4, 8, 14, 15}]]`, but it's not immediately clear if results for `ex[[{8, 14}]]` are correct or not. Let's plot them as a quick test:

```
Prepend[MapThread[
    Plot[#, {t, 0, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 16, 
      PlotLabel -> #2] &, {lst[[#, {1, 3, 4}]], {InverseLaplaceTransform, Integrate, 
      ContourIntegrate}}], #] & /@ {8, 14}
```

[image]

As shown above, `Integrate` doesn't handle `ex[[8]]` properly, but the inverse transform of `ex[[14]]` is correct.

To sum up, by setting $\gamma$ (`r` in code) in correct way, we now manage to calculate the inverse transform with `Integrate` for `ex[[{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 14, 15}]]`. If we turn to `ContourIntegrate`, we can further calculate inverse transform of `ex[[{7, 8, 9}]]`.

### Remark

1. It's a bit funny that for `ex[[3]]`, even `InverseLaplaceTransform` itself fails nowadays. By checking the legacy document, we can find this example has been removed in *v12.2*:

   [*v12.1* document](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v12.1/ref/InverseLaplaceTransform.html)

   [*v12.2* document](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v12.2/ref/InverseLaplaceTransform.html)
2. The assumption `t > 0` isn't actually necessary for `ContourIntegrate`.
3. Though owning the attribute `HoldAll`, `NIntegrate` suffers from the `I ∞` issue, too. See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175222/1871) for more info.
4. The following should be a correct setup for calculating Laplace inversion of `ex[[16]]`, but sadly it doesn't work at least for now:

   ```
    ilnew2[f_, s_, t_, line_] := 
     1/(2 π I) ContourIntegrate[f Exp[s t], s ∈ line, Assumptions -> t > 0]

    ilnew2[ex[[16]], s, t, HalfLine[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}} + Threaded@{1, 0}]] - 
      ilnew2[ex[[16]], s, t, 
       HalfLine[{{0, 0}, {1, -1}} + Threaded@{1, 0}]] // AbsoluteTiming
    (* ContourIntegrate returns unevaluated. *)
   ```