# Can Mathematica verify the Cahen - Mellin integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

Can Mathematica verify the [Cahen-Mellin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Cahen.E2.80.93Mellin_integral) integral?

When I try

```
Integrate[Gamma[1 + I s]/Zeta[3]^(1 + I s), {s, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I just get the input back. Thanks for any suggestion!

EDIT:

Numerically it is easy to get agreement:

```
NIntegrate[Gamma[1 + I s]/Zeta[3]^(1 + I s), {s, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> `1.88857 + 2.26472*10^-13 I`

```
2 \[Pi] Exp[-Zeta[3]] // N
```

> `1.88857`

But I wonder whether Mathematica more generally is capable of doing such integrals analytically.

Comment: So you just want to use `Integrate` rather than `InverseMellinTransform`? If so, slightly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81154/1871

Comment: Its nice to know that Mathematica has explicit mellin transform functions! Come to think of it, mathematica can't do `Integrate[Exp[I t q],{t,-Infinity,Infinity}]` either, but `FourierTransform[1,t,q]` works perfectly fine.