# Numerical Laplace transform error

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-transforms

I'm running Mathematica 11.3.0.0. The inverse Laplace transform of $1/(s^2-1)$, evaluated at $t=1$ gives

```
 InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(s^2 - 1), s, t] /. t -> 1    
 (* (-1 + E^2)/(2 E) *)
```

which is correct. Explicit evaluation as a symbolic integral

```
 (2*Pi*I)^(-1)*Integrate[Exp[s]/(s^2 - 1), {s, 2 - I*Infinity, 2 + I*Infinity}]
```

gives the same correct result $(e^2-1)/(2e)=1.1752$. However, numerical evaluation of the integral is way off,

```
 (2*Pi*I)^(-1)*NIntegrate[Exp[s]/(s^2 - 1), {s, 2 - I*Infinity, 2 + I*Infinity}]
 (* -0.18394 - 2.70877*10^-14 I *)
```

The imaginary part is negligibly small, as it should be, but the real part differs by almost a factor of ten from the correct value (without any error messages). Any idea what is going on?

---

As noted by AccidentalFourierTransform, the correct result is returned by

```
 (2*Pi*I)^(-1)*NIntegrate[Exp[s]/(s^2 - 1), {s, 2 - I*Infinity, 2,2 + I*Infinity}]
 (* 1.1752 + 0. I *)
```

Perhaps this is documented somewhere, that the integration path should be explicitly specified?

Comment: Interesting. It seems that for some reason you have to force the integration contour to go around the singularities on the right. The code `(2*Pi*I)^(-1)*
 NIntegrate[Exp[s]/(s^2 - 1), {s, 2 - I*Infinity, 2, 2 + I*Infinity}]` returns the correct result (notice the path, `{s, 2 - I*Infinity, 2, 2 + I*Infinity}`). Hmmm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amplifying @John's answer, first note:

```
2 - I Infinity //InputForm
```

> DirectedInfinity[-I]

The real part has been discarded. So both the [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) and [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) versions are using the limits:

```
{s, -I Infinity, I Infinity}
```

instead, with the real part suppressed. Now, the two outputs are different, so which is correct? Typically, when there is a discrepancy between [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) and [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) (where [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) produces a results without error messages), then it is more likely that [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) is correct, since [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) doesn't need to check branch cut/pole issues associated with the antiderivative that is computed by [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate). That is the case here. Compare:

```
Integrate[Exp[s]/(s^2-1),{s, -I*Infinity, I*Infinity}]/(2 Pi I) //N

NIntegrate[Exp[s]/(s^2-1),{s, -I*Infinity, I*Infinity}]/(2 Pi I)
```

> 1.1752
>
> -0.18394 - 2.70877*10^-14 I

The [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) result takes the difference of the antiderivative at the two limits of integration, but it may not be clear which path this result   corresponds to. On the other hand, the [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) result always uses the linear path between the limits, i.e., the path that goes through the origin. Redoing the integrals by specifying that the path goes through the origin:

```
Integrate[Exp[s]/(s^2-1),{s, -I*Infinity, 0, I*Infinity}]/(2 Pi I) //N

NIntegrate[Exp[s]/(s^2-1),{s, -I*Infinity, 0, I*Infinity}]/(2 Pi I)
```

> -0.18394 + 0. I
>
> -0.18394 - 2.70877*10^-14 I

Now, the two results agree.  If we use a path that goes through the point 2:

```
Integrate[Exp[s]/(s^2-1),{s, -I*Infinity, 2, I*Infinity}]/(2 Pi I) //N

NIntegrate[Exp[s]/(s^2-1),{s, -I*Infinity, 2, I*Infinity}]/(2 Pi I)
```

> 1.1752 + 0. I
>
> 1.1752 + 0. I

These results agree with the original [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) result, so we see that just subtracting the antiderivative at the limits of integration corresponds to the path that goes around the singularities at $\pm 1$ on the right.

**Addendum**

@xzczd asked whether it is possible to confirm that [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) does drop the real part. One piece of evidence:

```
Short[
    Last @ Reap @ NIntegrate[
        Exp[s]/(s^2-1),
        {s, 2-I Infinity, 2+I Infinity},
        EvaluationMonitor:>Sow[s]
    ],
    10
]
```

> {{0. -61.8145 I,0. -11.1974 I,0. -4.17292 I,0. -1.95969 I,0. -1. I,0. -0.510285 I,0. -0.23964 I,0. -0.0893062 I,0. -0.0161774 I,0. -374.81 I,0. -22.5193 I,0. -6.53258 I,0. -2.81288 I,0. -1.39298 I,0. -0.717883 I,<<236>>,0. -0.444442 I,0. -0.390297 I,0. -0.354513 I,0. -0.336879 I,0. -0.329806 I,0. -0.312805 I,0. -0.280854 I,0. -0.238097 I,0. -0.190411 I,0. -0.142857 I,0. -0.0989569 I,0. -0.0612234 I,0. -0.0317034 I,0. -0.0118667 I,0. -0.0019933 I}}

All of the evaluation points have a real part of `0.`

Comment: Hmm… `NIntegrate`  has the attribute `HoldAll`, doesn't it? Well, I know that `HoldAll` doesn't mean the argument will never be evaluated and `NIntegrate` does [evaluate its first argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118012/1871) after "hold" it, but, is there a way to verify that `2 - I Infinity` is indeed evaluated internally?

Comment: @xzczd See addendum.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on @AccidentalFourierTransform's comment, I suspect that `NIntegrate`, being a numerical method, evaluates the limits of integration numerically. `2 + I*Infinity` becomes `I*Infinity`, and the real displacement of the contour is lost. `Integrate`, which can deal in symbolic limits, seems to peek at the limits before evaluating, and figures out what you mean even though expressions like `2 + I*Infinity` are dubious.

Comment: Plausible. A possible evidence: `Clear[a]; NIntegrate[Exp[s]/(s^2 - 1), {s, a - I \[Infinity], a + I \[Infinity]}]/(2 \[Pi] I)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is already explained thoroughly [by Carl](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175222/1871), I just want to mention that in *v13.3* `ContourIntegrate` is introduced, which can avoid the issue caused by `I ∞` in a more natural way:

```
1/(2 π I) ContourIntegrate[Exp[s]/(s^2 - 1.), s ∈ InfiniteLine[{2, 0}, {0, 1}]]
```

[image]

`ContourIntegrate` can also be used to calculate the integral symbolically, of course:

```
1/(2 π I) ContourIntegrate[E^s/(s^2 - 1), s ∈ InfiniteLine[{2, 0}, {0, 1}]]
```

[image]