# Inconsistency between Plot and NIntegrate

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, evaluation

Have a look at the following definition

```
Y[q_, w_ /; w < 0] := 0
Y[q_, w_] := w
```

The function `Y` is zero for negative `w`. It is indeed so when we plot it

```
Plot[Y[0.5, e], {e, -2, -1}]
```

Now we integrate zero and get -1.5

```
NIntegrate[Y[0.5, e], {e, -2, -1}]
```

What is wrong here? What command `Plot`or `NIntegrate` behave correctly according to the MA syntax?

According to the [Wolfram Language Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheOrderingOfDefinitions.html)

- The Wolfram System tries to put specific definitions before more
  general definitions.
- Whenever the appropriate ordering is not clear,
  the Wolfram System stores rules in the order you give them.

In this particular case we can check that the result is indeed zero.

```
Y[0.5,-1]
(* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a matter of evaluation order. First of all, notice under your definition, any `w` that doesn't satisfy `w < 0` will match the second definition, for example

```
Clear[e]
Y[0.5, e]
(* e *)
```

Then why does `Plot` choose the first definition of `Y`? Because, as mentioned in **Details and Options** section of document of `Plot`:

> `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll` and evaluates `f` only after assigning specific numerical values to `x`.

Then why does `NIntegrate` behave differently? It owns attribute `HoldAll`, too! That's because owning `HoldAll` doesn't necessarily mean the argument will never be evaluated. Actually `NIntegrate` evaluates the arguments once they're `Block`ed. This is also mentioned in the document (in **Details and Options** section of document of `NIntegrate`):

> `NIntegrate` first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates `f` with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically.

This behavior has been discussed in the following posts, too:

[NIntegrate evaluates its 1st argument while it has the attribute HoldAll?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117994/1871)

[Numerical Laplace transform error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175169/1871)

Finally, as already mentioned by [Ulrich Neumann](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53677/ulrich-neumann), one can make `Plot` behave like `NIntegrate` by adding the undocumented option `Evaluated`:

```
Plot[Y[0.5, e], {e, -2, -1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

Or simply `Evaluate`:

```
Plot[Y[0.5, e] // Evaluate, {e, -2, -1}]
```

Is it possible to make `NIntegrate` behave like `Plot`? Sadly `Evaluated` isn't an option of `NIntegrate`, but we can make use of `NumericQ`:

```
help[e_?NumericQ] := Y[0.5, e]
NIntegrate[help[e], {e, -2, -1}]
```

BTW, when defining piecewise functions, it's not a good idea to use `Condition` (`/;`). It doesn't work well with all the functions for simplification (`Simplify`, etc.), it's not suitable for numeric evaluation, either. (Because it's based on pattern matching. ) `Piecewise` is a much better choice. (Don't forget you can create it with <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. )

Comment: I do not completely understand. You are saying that the observed result on `NIntegrate`  is actually coming from the symbolic evaluation. But now let us change to `NIntegrate[Y[0.5, -Exp[Exp[Exp[e]]]], {e, 0, 1}]`. It cannot be computed symbolically, yet the result is not zero! In contrast `Y[q_, w_?NumericQ] := 0 /; w < 0`and `Y[q_, w_?NumericQ] := w` leads to zero in both cases.  Can you please comment on this.

Comment: It comes from symbolic evaluation of **integrand** i.e. `Y[0.5, -Exp[Exp[Exp[e]]]]` first evaluate to `-E^E^E^e`.

Answer (score 2):

Your second definition of Y overwrites the first. That's why MMA evaluates `Y[q,w]->w`  !

Try

```
Y[q_, w_ /; w < 0] := 0
Y[q_, w_ /; w >= 0] := w

NIntegrate[Y[0.5, e], {e, -2, -1}]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Not quite for 2 reasons: 1) exchanging the order of definitions does not change anything; 2) assuming that my second definition indeed has a priority, why then it is not visible in Plot? I believe that Plot has to be consistent with NIntegrate no matter what the function is. Suspect a bug...

Comment: Don't know why `Plot` works. But everything works as expected if you use a clean function definition , for example `Y[q_, w_] := Which[w < 0, 0, True, w]`

Comment: @  yarchik : Add Evaluate in your plot-command `Plot[Y[0.5, e], {e, -2, -1},Evaluated -> True]` and you will see the correct plot! No bug!!

Comment: Why then `Y[0.5,-1]` returns zero?

Comment: Because MMA takes the first matching definition.

Comment: But why then MMA does not take the first matching definition for the integral? Should be consistent. By the way, see my updated question where I quote some passages from the documentation.

Comment: Because NIntegrate `Evaluates` its argument.

Comment: Can well be, but is it obvious that `Evaluate` should exchange the order of definitions? If you know something more on this matter you can update your answer. But I could not find anything in  the documentation about this.

Comment: The word _overwrite_ is misleading, I should say.