# Conditional statement in function

Tags: symbolic, summation, conditional

It seems the equality condition does not work as expected.

```
deq[m_] := If[m===0,p+1,2 (p+1-m)]
dle1[m_] := Sum[ deq[i],{i,0,m} ]
dle2[m_] := Sum[ deq[i],{i,1,m} ] + (p+1)

Echo[dle1[p]]
Echo[dle2[p]]
```

Here is the output

```
In[5]:= >> (1 + p) (2 + p)

Out[5]= (1 + p) (2 + p)

In[6]:=               2
>> 1 + 2 p + p

                   2
Out[6]= 1 + 2 p + p
```

It may be because the symbol `i` is not replace by `0`. I tried with `==` but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: Do you have a numerical value for `p`? How is `Sum` supposed to know how many terms to sum over? Also you definitely want `m == 0`. If I make that change and evaluate `dle1[5]` I get a totally reasonable result.

Comment: What did you expect actually?  You don't need `Echo`.

Comment: b3m2a1 : it is just linear in m, it should be able to compute the sum with p being not set. I do not want to fix p to a numerical value

@Pierre ALBARÈDE, I expect the `Out[6]`. It seems that for `Out[5]` he replaces `dle1[0]` by $2 (p+1)$ instead of $2p$,

Comment: Can you post the respective inputs In[5] In[6]?  You can copy cell as Input text and paste here.  Like In[73]:= 2 + 3

Out[73]= 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by b3m2a1 in [the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216765/conditional-statement-in-function#comment553961_216765). Using `==` instead of `===` results in the correct result:

```
deq[m_] := If[m == 0, p + 1, 2 (p + 1 - m)]
dle1[m_] := Sum[deq[i], {i, 0, m}]
dle2[m_] := Sum[deq[i], {i, 1, m}] + (p + 1)

dle1[p]
(* Piecewise[{{1 + p, p <= 0}}, 1 + 2*p + p^2] *)

dle2[p]
(* 1 + p + Piecewise[{{2*p, p == 1}}, p + p^2] *)
```

The output involves `Piecewise`, but it's easy to notice the result is correct.

Then why does `===` cause problem here? We turn to `Trace`:

```
deq[m_] := If[m === 0, p + 1, 2 (p + 1 - m)]
dle1[p] // Trace
```

[image]

As we can see, `deq[i]` is evaluated inside `Sum`, and `i === 0` evaluates to `False`, so `deq[i]` becomes `2 (p + 1 - m)`, which is undesired. That's al——

No, that's not the end.

If you know a little about attribute, you may feel surprising that `deq[i]` is evaluated inside `Sum`: `Sum` owns the attribute `HoldAll`! This is because a function with attribute `HoldAll` only holds the argument of function. Once the argument goes *into* the function, there's no guarantee it'll never be evaluated. A simple example:

```
ClearAll[f, g]
Attributes[f] = {HoldAll};
Attributes[g] = {HoldAll};
g[a_] := a

f[1 + 1]
(* f[1 + 1] *)
g[1 + 1]
(* 2 *)
```

The following is another example about functions with `HoldAll` attribute evaluating their arguments internally:

[Inconsistency between Plot and NIntegrate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/201355/1871)

Answer (score 2):

You get what you expect, if you don't use Setdelayed `:=` for fundtion definitions.

```
{deq[m_] = If[m == 0, p + 1, 2 (p + 1 - m)],
 dle1[m_] = Sum[deq[i], {i, 0, m}],
 dle2[m_] = Sum[deq[i], {i, 1, m}] + (p + 1),
 dle1[p],
 dle2[p]} // Simplify // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Actually `:=` isn't related here. It's all because you've used `===` instead of `==`.